# How can I declare globle variable in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have to declare x variable in render method and use in outer method.

```
    var x = document.getElementById('pick').value
```

But it error shows that x is not defined.How can i define it other way?thank you.Here is full code

```
handleSelect(key) {

if(key == 1){
    window.location.href = '/portfolio.html?'+x;
}

if(key == 2){ 
    window.location.href = '/transaction.html?'+x;
}
},

render:function() {

return (
  <div>
  <Tabs activeKey={this.state.key} onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
    <Tab eventKey={0} title="home"> </Tab>
    <Tab eventKey={1} title="Tab 1">Tab 1 content</Tab>
    <Tab eventKey={2} title="Tab 2">Tab 2 content</Tab>
    <Tab eventKey={3} title="Tab 3">Tab 3 content</Tab>
  </Tabs>

  <h1>here is your portfolio list</h1> <br/>

  <select id="pick">
    { 
      this.state.data.map(function(data) {  
        return <option value={data.id}>{data.name}</option>               
      })
    }

  </select>
    {

       if(this.state.data.length > 0)
        window.x = document.getElementById('pick').value

    }
 </div> 
 );
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Common JS based pattern, using module.exports, any vars are by default local. Ignoring that what you are trying to do is not a recommended practice, you should be able to make it work by declaring as -

```
window.somevar = value;
```

And use it like -

```
if (window.someVar){...}
```

Comment: Several things wrong with your code... You should use state to store component data instead of x. Don't use id, use ref to retrieve value. Finally, never ever use render for fetching dom values, the component isn't mounted yet. Use componentDidMount.

Answer (score 0):

You can set global variable without `var`

```
 x = document.getElementById('pick').value
or
window.x = document.getElementById('pick').value
```

Comment: fine, may be it will work but i have to use 'if' incase it is null or not? any suggestion?

Comment: you can check : if(x) {}